# Codeigniter HMVC: I can't call "database" library inside controller

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, hmvc

I've ran into a problem that can't seem to have an answer.

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.4 with HMVC.

My question is: **How can I load a core library in a controller of a module?**

I want to load the "database" library (which is a core library) inside a method of a controller (or model for that matter) in order to avoid connecting to the database if there is no need to do it (when i have cached results inside a text file).

I understand that you can use autoload per module, but I only want to load the library if some conditions are met.

I also know you can load libraries that are inside the libraries folder of the module folder, but if I only need one database why would I paste the database library inside every single module just to make the connection.

When I try to load the library with "$this->load->library('database');", it gives me the following error:"Unable to load the requested class: database". Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a database with:

```
$this -> load -> database();
```

Whenever you want to load a specific database, you give the name of the database to the load function:

```
$this -> load -> database('DBname');
```

Where you specify your database propeties in `config\database.php`.
Note that you define your database name/group with the first key:

```
$db['This is your database group']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

see **[here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html)**.

---

Hope this was helpful.